# Android AeroGear Rest error java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: android, keycloak, aerogear

Please am getting Stream closed when is try to retrieve data from a Restfull API using aerogear pipe
....

```
AuthzModule authzModule = AuthorizationManager.getModule("KeyCloakAuthz");

authzModule.requestAccess( (Activity)this, new Callback<String>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
          Pipe<Transactions> pipes = PipeManager.getPipe("transactions");
          pipes.read(new AbstractCallback<List<Transactions>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Transactions> id) {
              //nothink happen
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            //error stream closed
            }
```

could you help me please thanks